# Parallel for loops in R

Tags: r, for-loop, parallel-processing

Test functions for reproducible example:

```
progress <- function(text) {
  cat(sprintf(paste0(as.character(Sys.time()), ": Task ", text, " completed!\n")))
}

functionThatDoesSomething <- function(x) {
  return(x)
}
```

No parallelization:

```
ptm <- proc.time()
for(i in seq(1, 10000)) {
  progress(i)
  x = functionThatDoesSomething(i) #calling a function
}
proc.time() - ptm

# user  system elapsed 
# 0.953   0.021   0.952
```

Parallelization with `doSNOW`:

```
suppressMessages(library(doSNOW))
suppressMessages(library(parallel))
ncores <- detectCores()/2
cl <- makeCluster(ncores, outfile="")
registerDoSNOW(cl)

ptm <- proc.time()
res <- foreach(w = seq(1, 10000), .options.snow=list(progress=progress)) %dopar% {
  tmp = functionThatDoesSomething(w) #calling a function
}
proc.time() - ptm
stopCluster(cl)
# user  system elapsed 
# 5.352   0.538   5.667
```

I'm not seeing a speed up when I try to parallel this very basic code. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Probably because the overhead associated with foreach is greater than any savings achieved by parallelizing a function as trivial as `return(x)`.  Try a real use case for `functionThatDoesSomething()`.  Also, the worker isn't returning anything, just assigning to `tmp`.

Comment: Overhead associated with `foreach` includes connecting to the worker, and exporting objects/libraries to each worker.

Comment: Okay I see. I would have approx 200M items to iterate over in the worst case and am looking for the best methods to do this.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 I have changed `functionThatDoesSomething()` to return `x^2 + 1 - 100` and there still is no speed up. Parallelization is still slower. I've even tried it iterate `i=1:100000`.

Comment: that's not a real use case either since the vectorized approach (`seq(1:1000)^2+1-100`) is the way to go.  It sounds like your question is "please give me an example of where `foreach` is faster than `for`... is this correct?

Comment: Ah agreed. Realistically the `functionThatDoesSomething()` would compute part of a computational method that involves range intersections. I have not yet implemented this yet though.

Comment: Implement it and go back with an edited function that we can work with :')

Comment: Foreach is firing off each individual loop index, thus the huge overhead.  You can do better with something like `foreach(w=iter(1:10000, chunksize=1000)...` (e.g. https://ljdursi.github.io/beyond-single-core-R/#/90 ) but `clusterMap()` would be even faster.  But the other commenters are correct, really need the real use case before performance recommendations can be made, even in serial - in parallel, more so.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 - Yes, I suppose that's a better question to ask for this application.

Comment: if I include the `chunksize=1000` argument, then my output is only 1 task and contains only 1 value. Not really sure whats going on here. I guess I will have to look into `clusterMap()`!